# What is the name of a film about three brothers saying the Jesus prayer?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, reference-request, culture

I recently learned about a short film featuring three brothers who live on an island. They are (Russian?) Orthodox Christians and practice the Jesus prayer. Eventually, word of their holiness spreads and they are visited by some clergy. Does anyone know the name of this short film?

Comment: Well the film sounds like it's based off a Leo Tolstoy story called [The Three Hermits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Hermits)

Comment: -1 This is not a movie QA site.

Comment: While this [is likely on-topic here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4086/20), it's clearly on-topic on [Movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/), and may get a better answer there.

Comment: @Dejan: We permit "identify this" questions, as long as they are about "Christian things," so movie identifcation questions are expressly on-topic here--if the movie is of a Christian nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUFwTctEFxE)

From:

[What is Augustine's original of Tolstoy's "Three Hermits" story?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/what-is-augustines-original-of-tolstoys-three-hermits-story)

Comment: Please accept your own answer, if it is correct.